# will the average person make it into Olam Haba

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come

will the average Jew who presumably has a big accumulated package of sins and also a big package of good deeds make it into Olam Haba?

is there a minimum requirement for one to "get in"?

Comment: כל ישראל יש להם חלק לעולם הבא

Comment: @Yishai has, but can lose it.

Comment: I think so, but can't remember an explicit source.

Comment: @Shmuel you think what?

Comment: That an average בינוני does get in.

Comment: Is there any reason to think there is some rule? Every Jew is different, so the average Jew today is not the same as the average Jew tomorrow or yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

דרך ה' חלק ב פרק ב סימן ד

> ואמנם גזר עוד חסדו ית' להרבות ההצלה לבני האדם, שימצא עוד מין צירוף אחר למי שיתכן בו הצירוף, דהיינו **למי שגבר בו הרע תגבורת גדול**, אך לא כל כך שיהיה משפטו להאבידו לגמרי, והוא כלל עונשים שהיותר רשום בהם הוא הדין בגהינם. והכונה בו הוא להעניש החוטא כפי חטאיו, באופן שאחרי הענשו לא יהיה עוד חוב עליו על המעשה הרע שעשה, ויוכל אחרי כן לקבל הגמול האמיתי כפי שאר מעשיו הטובים. ונמצא שעל ידי זה, האובדים ממש יהיו מזער לא כביר, כי הנה לא יהיו אלא אותם שגבר בהם הרע שיעור כל כך גדול, שאי אפשר שימצא להם מקום בשום פנים להיות נשארים בגמול האמיתי ובהנאה הנצחיית

Summary translation: Hashem made it such that a person who has done much evil, but not so much as to deserve complete destruction, will get punished, primarily with Gehinnom, and subsequently will have no further dues for his misdeeds, and can then get rewarded for his positive actions.  Only an incredibly minute fraction of people, those who are so evil that it is impossible to find any way to include them in the true reward, will be destroyed.

Comment: nice source. is this a minority opinion though? the ramban for example holds that anyone who incurred karet is destroyed in the next world and the steipler shows just how easy it is to be chayiv karet.

Comment: Of course, one can do sincere tshuvah, and erase the evil deeds.  It's astounding how often we forget that.